# how do stop Alert Api from crashing my React native app?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying link a URL to a TouchableOpacity component through the Alert API, which gives the user to option to cancel the link or progress forward. However when I assign the the function to the onpress method and press the method, it crashes my app. is there a work around to this?

here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, Linking, TouchableOpacity, View,ImageBackground, Alert } from 'react-native'
import styles from './styles';
import { firebase } from '../../firebase/config';
import { auth } from 'firebase';
import {Spacer} from '../spacer';



export default function ProductScreen({navigation}){

    const logOutPress = () => {
        auth()
        .signOut()
        .then(() => { navigation.navigate("Login"),
        alert('You have signed out')})
    }

   const yalaPress = () =>  Alert.alert( "You're about to leave the app",[
    { text: "Cancel",
        onPress: ()=> console.log('Cancel Pressed')},
    {text: "Ok", 
        onPress: () => Linking.openURL('http://yalajets.com/')
    }],{ cancelable: false }  );


    return(
<ImageBackground source={require('../../../assets/backgroundCopySilk.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
<View style={styles.container}>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Luxury Commercial Lawn Care</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Luxury Vehicle Car Detail</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Luxury Pharmaceuticals</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Luxury Personal Fitness</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Luxury Massage with Catch These Hands</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity 
onPress={yalaPress}
style={styles.button}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Luxury Private Flights with Yala Jets</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<Spacer/>
<TouchableOpacity
onPress={()=> logOutPress()}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Log Out</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
</ImageBackground>
    )
};
```

Comment: Try with https url

Comment: No that didnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `yalaPress` to this:

```
const yalaPress = () => {
  Alert.alert(
    'Warning',
    "You're about to leave the app",
    [
      {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed!')},
      {text: 'OK', onPress: () => Linking.openURL('http://yalajets.com/')},
    ],
    {cancelable: false},
  );
};
```

Also change how you call `yalaPress` to this:

```
onPress={() => yalaPress()}
```

The reason the alert crashed is because Alert expects a title and a message. You only passed a title, and the message is required.